# VS Code Explorer is not showing any project directory or files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this one project for which VS Code is not showing any files or directories in the Explorer tree

[image]

The actual project files and directories at the root are these:

[image]

VS Code is working fine for other projects.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing the folders inside `~/Library/Application Support/Code/` (except the `User/` folder because that contains your keybindings and settings configurations) and then restart Code.

Comment: Specific to the question , alfonso's seems to be answer. because its possibly a cache issue, but if some one is looking for a scenario where certain files are missing, possibly where files mentioned in git ignore are missing you have to check this setting.  Explorer: Exclude Git Ignore

Answer (score 54):

Open the VS Code [**Command Palette**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).
You can use shortcut keys to open the command palette:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux)
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac)

Then search for: **View: Reset View Locations**

It should reset the view.

Link to VS Code's UI docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

Comment: Obviously, for a Mac I had to use `command + shift + P`.

Answer (score 26):

Another solution: Go to Settings and check "Files: Exclude" in both "User Settings" and "Workspace Settings". Delete the files/folders needed to appear.

Answer (score 9):

First, make sure you open a non-empty folder.

If you cannot see any files, it is likely that "Folders" is hidden or dragged into other views. To resolve this, open the [**Command Palette**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Windows/Linux, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Mac).

Then input **View Folders**. From there you can find where exactly "Folders" is, then just re-drag it into the Explorer. In my case, I found "Folders" is dragged into terminal accidentally.

If there are still no files displayed, please check **Settings > Commonly Used > Files Exclude** as the other answers explain.

Comment: This is what happened to me. Folders was dragged into the sidebar, next to Explorer, making it it's own View instead of being part of Explorer. I had to drag it back into the Explorer View. Just open Explorer View and drag the Folders icon from the sidebar into Explorer below Open Editors and above NPM Scripts.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me a while ago and it took me over a month to realize what was happening.  In my case, for some reason I added the glob pattern "**/*" for the property Files: Exclude.  Basically, I told vscode to exlude all the files in the project, just remove the pattern and you should be fine[image]. I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Confoundingly, vscode does not show all the files and directories in a project.  I happened to figure that out when I was using the command line to look for a directory, and I found it, but then I noticed vscode was not showing that directory.  Wtf?!  Thanks for your post. To see what files vscode chose to "exclude" in my Phoenix application (on macOS),  in the vscode menu bar: `Code>Preferences>Settings` then in the displayed pane: `Text Editor>Files`, then I scrolled down to a heading that said "Exclude".  In my case, I deleted `**/priv/static`

Answer (score 4):

I had that same problem today (Version: 1.61.0) and fixed it by:

1. Opening ("Open...") another project on which folders WERE shown.
2. Opening the original project right after by selecting ("Open..."), but NOT "Open Recent".

Answer (score 4):

In vscode press **CRTL** + **SHIFT** + **E** it will make explorer visible, then right click on explorer -> **Keep "Explorer"**.

Comment: This solved it for me. I had by mistake tucked my file explorer away and could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and the issue turned out to be missing macos file system permissions.

I opened a file in the directory using the CLI `code myfile.txt` instead of the entire directory with `code .`, and VSCode then shows a useful error message.

```
The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: 
Unable to read file '/Users/myuser/Documents/mycode/myfile.txt' 
(NoPermissions (FileSystemError): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.)
```

I fixed the issue by adding permission for the VSCode app under Security & Privacy > Files and Folders > VSCode > Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way it worked for me was to drag the folders from Windows Explorer into VS Code. That restored the entire directory tree for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this for a while but I figured out it was a permissions error. Run `ls` in the terminal to see if you have the same error as me, if you do it should tell you permission denied.

The fix is very easy:

```
sudo bash
chmod 775 .
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I reinstalled the vscode and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code was enough for me to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

For me removing my cache, or resetting the "Files: Exclude" did not work, what did work was resetting the primary sidebar.

Open the commands textbox with CMD/CTRL+p and then enter the `command > Reset View Locations`

Answer (score 0):

Someone in Githup/Microsoft/vscode/issues have been said that "delete the C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage folder", and it worked for me. I uninstalled vscode also looked settings suggestion above. nothing worked but this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, folder gets added to the terminal. Go to View > Terminal, Right click on folder displayed and select Reset Location as shown below. Now the folder will be directly visible under explorer tree.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

create a folder using terminal with command "mkdir folder-name" then go to "file" in menu and then to "open folder" then select the folder u used while creating mkdir. This woked for me.

Answer (score -3):

go to the directory you want then press right click and press open with then select vs code