# File explorer disappeared in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

After updating vscode to version February 2023 (version 1.76) File explorer is completely gone.

I have tried looking around in many places and commands, using Shift+cmd+E and nothing happens.

It is not shown in the side panel check mark as an available icon

[image: 1]

I have tried looking around vscode and internet but my problem seems not to be the same. I am expecting to be able to use this button as an available options to manage files.

Comment: Try resetting your view locations command: `View: Reset View Locations` and see if it helps.  And check to see if it is the secondary side bar: Configure Layout button on the upper right and click Secondary Side Bar.

Comment: Mark thank you so much, Reset view locations fixed it.

Comment: Right click any of the icons on the leftmost toolbar (ie. the vertical row where the icon is missing :).... Then you will know the answer to it all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code Explorer is not showing any project directory or files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851552/vs-code-explorer-is-not-showing-any-project-directory-or-files)

Answer (score 184):

Run this command:

```
View: Reset View Locations
```

and the Explorer should come back.

Note: To run a vscode command, open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) by pressing:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux)
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac)

Probably the same issue: [File Explorer gone missing...](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177076)

This has arisen a couple of times after upgrading to vscode 1.76.

Answer (score 21):

CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Reset View Locations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This seems to essentially duplicate [Mark's answer](/a/75740292/4518341). Please don't post duplicate answers. If you want to add the keyboard shortcut to Mark's answer, please [submit an edit](/help/editing). Stack Overflow is like Wikipedia in that respect.

Answer (score 6):

Even after following all the following all the above solutions, the problem keep recurring.

The following is the permanent fix: `Right click, the Primary Side Bar then Mark the explorer option as checked`

[image]

And Walaaa!! Problem solved.

Comment: I had to hide and show Explorer.  Don't expect much from "C# Dev Kit"....  None of the "Reset View Locations" did anything.  VSC 1.86.1 C# Dev Kit v1.3.10

Answer (score 3):

open status bar, than you find file explorer option. Then click mouse right button on explorer. Then select reset location. Or please follow these, https://medium.com/@mdfaishal329/vs-code-file-explorer-missing-how-to-fix-it-c031b255469b

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly enough i got it to work after toggling on **Activity Bar**.

From **View** > **Appearance** > **Activity Bar Position** > **Side**.

Then if you want to hide Activity Bar like i do follow the same steps and click on Hide from **Activity Bar Position**

Comment: I've had the same problem, however when hiding the activity bar the explorer goes missing again. I've had to keep the activity bar visible for now.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` , `view: Show Explorer` ,  `Enter`

After this, right click on the menu on the left and check the `Explorer` option: if you don't do this, the File Explorer will keep disappearing

Comment: Its odd but I only get `view: Show Remote Explorer`, `view: Show Explorer` is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing Visual Studio Code (version 1.84.2) and here is how I fixed my problem;

- On VS Code, access the **Command Palette** by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+P**
- Enter this command: **View: Reset View Locations**
  This should reset the locations of the components like Explorer, Search, Source Control etc.

[image]

Comment: This seems to essentially duplicate [Mark's answer](/a/75740292/4518341) as well as [Snehal's answer](/a/77025273/4518341). Please don't post duplicate answers. Instead, you can add details to an existing answer by [submitting an edit](/help/editing). Stack Overflow is like Wikipedia in that respect.

Comment: I went ahead and added most of the details myself. If you want to add anything else, like what exactly the command does, by all means.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

```
On VS Code, access the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P
```

Enter this command: View: Reset All Menus