# VSCode Explorer Not Showing (MAC OS)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBCzZ.png)

The File Explorer is not displayed.

It is also not displayed when right-clicked.
Pressing Shift+Command+E has no response.

This is the same situation if you reset the settings and reinstall them.

How can we resolve this situation?

OS : MacOS Monterey 12.6 /
VSCode Version: 1.76.1 (Universal)

Comment: Does `View: Reset View Locations` help?

Comment: I made it into an answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740292/836330 - an older question than yours.

Comment: @Mark It seems to be a bug that occurred after VSCode update.

Thank you for letting me know the cause.