# Why is folders missing from my VS Code Explorer menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What settings exist in VS Code to allow me to see my folders in the Explorer Menu? I know they should be there, but in this view (below), they are not display and without them, I can't view or work on my project.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find and restore a missing View or View subsection in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76144000/how-can-i-find-and-restore-a-missing-view-or-view-subsection-in-vs-code)

Comment: No. That deals with viewing all of the subfolders, but I can't even display the folders to begin with.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740292/836330 for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a folder open. You need to open a folder to see the files inside of it. Once you do, you will see it in the explorer.

Without a folder open.[image]

With a folder open. [image]

There are a few ways to open a folder.   If you navigate to the welcome tab, you will see a prompt to open a folder. [image]

Or you can use the shortcut, on mac its Cmd + O to open a folder or a file, its Ctrl + O on Windows.

Or you can navigate using the application menu in your operating system. Its File > Open Folder.

Comment: I did have a folder open. I tried opening a folder from within VS Code, and I tried opening the folder using VS Code from the context menu. The folder simply won't open.