# Visual Studio Code not opening folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode editor doesn't show the folder structure in the explorer view in spite folder is open (verified in terminal path). Tried removing hidden folders in settings
[Screenshot of vscode editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmuMd.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692236/file-explorer-disappeared-in-visual-studio-code/75740292#75740292 may help.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a folder by clicking on the corresponing option (middle of your screenshot). The terminal window and the folder are NOT synchronized but per default a new terminal window starts in your current folder.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics for more details.

Comment: I tried opening a folder by clicking one from my recent and also opening a folder from start (options present in the middle of the screen). Still my issue persists

Comment: Have you tried the ideas in [VS Code Explorer is not showing any project directory or files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851552/vs-code-explorer-is-not-showing-any-project-directory-or-files)?