# Why is VS Code not showing my folder in the explorer bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make the "folder" option appear in VS Code's explorer?

I was configuring my workspace and it disappeared for no reason.

It should show an option "folder" right here:

[image]

I tried to configure it in the settings but I really don't know where I can find this configuration.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692236/file-explorer-disappeared-in-visual-studio-code/75740292#75740292

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code Explorer is not showing any project directory or files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851552/vs-code-explorer-is-not-showing-any-project-directory-or-files)